# How to replace choices list for TypedChoiceField in Django form?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a class which includes a field with a choice list:

```
class Game(models.Model):
    track = models.CharField(max_length=5,
                             choices=AllTracks.TRACK_CHOICES)
```

I want to use a form based on this model, but I want to pass it a subset of the choice list, `PublicTracks.TRACK_CHOICES`.

I've looked at the structure of the form. In the `base_fields` dictionary, `track` is a `TypedChoiceField` object. That object has an attribute `choices`, which is `list(AllTracks.TRACK_CHOICES)`. I've tried replacing it with `list(AllTracks.TRACK_CHOICES)` but it doesn't seem to take.

Any suggestions on how I might override the list from the model definition would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a completely custom field on your form class, overriding the one that would be auto-generated from your model otherwise, as described in [Overriding the default fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields):

```
class GameForm(forms.ModelForm):

    track = forms.ChoiceField(choices=WHATEVER, ...)

    class Meta(object):
        model = Game
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Now, I don't suppose you have a suggestion for telling it to render that field _before_ the fields from the meta class, so that I can still use `{{ event_form }}` and not have to enumerate the fields in my template? The docs just say to put the fields in display order, but even though `track` is now defined before the rest it's showing up at the bottom.

Comment: Adding an explicit `GameForm.Meta.fields` tuple listing your fields in the desired order should do the trick.

Comment: Ah, I see. I already had fields defined with the fields from the model, but my local definition of track overrides it. Spiffy!